# node-schedule-tz : Issue with timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduled-tasks

Why doesn't this work?

```
var tournRule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
tournRule.dayOfWeek = 3;
tournRule.hour = 03;
tournRule.minute = 08;
tournRule.tz = 'Central Time';
```

I have tried inputting so many different things into the **.tz = 'CDT'; section but no matter what, it doesn't trigger. I'm getting no errors at all from it.

Tia!

**EDIT**

Thought I should add this too :

```
var tr = schedule.scheduleJob(tournRule, function() {
console.log("Im online. Im online");
})
```

**EDIT 2**

I want to specify the timezone as the ESL team I am developing the bot for have different schedules for Central US Players and UK Players.

Comment: Have a look at my answer @BretHawker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest trying the cron package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron.

I've found this to work nicely with timezones, an example is here:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const job = new CronJob({
  // Run at 05:00 Central time, only on weekdays
  cronTime: '00 00 05 * * 1-5',
  onTick: function() {
      // Run whatever you like here..
      console.log('CronJob ran!!');
  },
  start: true,
  timeZone: 'US/Central'
});
```

See here for a list of timezones:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 1):

From the [project's readme on GitHub](https://github.com/kqkq/node-schedule-tz#readme):

> If a timezone is specified, a **job name** must be specified as well as the first parameter.

For the event to be triggered you have to specify a job name as the first parameter:

```
schedule.scheduleJob('job name', '0 14 * * *', 'Asia/Shanghai', () => {
    console.log('Will execute on 14:00:00 GMT+8:00 (CST) everyday');
});
```

** As of now, the project's npm page says nothing about the `job name` requirement. It's only documented on the GitHub [readme file](https://github.com/kqkq/node-schedule-tz#readme).*

Answer (score -1):

according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule-tz you don't have to specify timezone, here's working example from their site:

```
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.minute = 42;

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
    console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

example above will trigger in every hour ending with :42, like 7:42, 8:42, 9:42 etc, make sure you understand how cron-like things work

Comment: Let me edit my question so that you may edit your answer.

Comment: so the possibilities are you type timezone name incorrectly or time on your server isn't working properly, because your code is technically correct, only thing that could be wrong from my point of view is timezone name or something is messed with your server